# How can any cellphone LCD be used as a portable monitor?

Tags: camera, screen, monitoring, lcd

In simple, I just want to build some thing like :

CC TV with small monitor and small camera (the smaller the both, the better).
.
For example, I need it to connect a camera so I can watch real time caption.
The camera is not some thing predefined, it can be cellphone camera as well.

I just was wondering, how can I only salvage this 2 parts from a broken mobile, functioning like CCTV camera and monitor.
The next phase, could be adding WiFi modules to both camera and screen.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider it's almost impossible to use a random screen with your rpi ...

If you are extremely lucky, you will be able to find your screen reference on this [github wiki](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki).
In other cases, you will need to write or adapt by yourself the driver for your specific screen, wich is an hard task for an expert.

Be kind with yourself, buy a 3.5" touchscreen compatible with the pi, you will save a lot of time and loose only 15-30$ !

Note : idem about the camera.
Most of the USB cameras are compatible with the rpi, first price are around 5$ ! 
If you want to keep it small, the rpiCam is also really wonderful ! (around 30$)